# Android Studio in Windows 10 not launch after installing Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.2

in windows 10 in Android Studio 3.2.1
the application is worked correctly after first time of installing but after installing **Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)** from : 
**File > Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories**
after installing the plugin android studio should restart and then it's can't launch anymore

anyone can help please ?

Comment: That's a "beta" so, why don't you try to delete the configuration directory of the Android Studio in `C:/users/<yourUsername>/androidStudio` version? This should remove the config + installed plugins and you'll be able to run the App without reinstalling it again.

Comment: the problem is that I want to use that plugin@Mohsen

Comment: I get it. But it seems like because it's in beta release, might have some issues like now. You can report the issue to the developer or IssueTracker for the future releases but for now, the only solution will be deleting that directory so that you can use Android Studio again without reinstalling it.

Comment: thanks for your advice , I will work for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot just use any version of [Google Sceneform Tools ​(Beta)​](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10698-google-sceneform-tools-beta-) with any version of Android Studio. As this one [comment](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/993#issuecomment-593414643) suggests, even if it's about other versions (also see the other comments there):

> A temporary solution: install Android Studio 3.5.1 + Sceneform 1.5, make sfb file, place in project in Android Studio 3.6.

So in your case, you might probably have to update to Android Studio version `3.5.3` or any other version, which works with the current version `1.16.0`, as the Android Studio which you are using appears rather outdated.

If you just want to be able to start Android Studio again, then manually delete the plugin directory from `%USERPROFILE%/.AndroidStudio3.2/config/plugins`, in order to perform a manual uninstall, as it might be required in order to update Android Studio.

Besides "it's not working" is not an error description. You'd have to start Android Studio from the command line, in order to get some meaningful error message, by which you then could search in the issues on GitHub (if the reason why it doesn't start up anymore might have another cause).

Answer (score 0):

I have had [issue #377](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/377) filed for this plugin since Oct 16, 2018, and unfortunately it is still open now.

I will update this answer if it is solved or a solution is found.

**Update 1 :**
the github [[repository](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk)][2](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk) for this plugin has been archived and it seems no longer supported after reading the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/getting-started)